# How can I reduce the outer diameter of galvanized steel pipes by .1-.2mm?

Tags: pipe, table, pipe-fitting

Is there a way to take off.1-.2mm from a steel pipe (1/2 inch ID)

I am building several desks and a table. I am using pipes for legs, but the **inner** diameter of the fittings I ordered is maybe .1-.2mm bigger than the **outer** diameter of the galvanized pipes I currently have. Yesterday I let the tips of the pipes soak in 5% HCl mixture for roughly 2 hours, in hopes that it would [de-galvanize the pipes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puZIs.jpg) and eat away at the steel a bit. It ate through the zinc in maybe 15 minutes but didn't seem to take much of the steel off as it was still too big of the [fittings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T71m.jpg).
Another problem I ran into was a [bulge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHoFg.jpg) on the tips of the pipes where I cut them (w/ a pipe cutter). I did a test fitting with one of the edge pieces (meaning one side didn't have a bulge), and it still seemed to be too tight.

-open to all ideas, my fiancée is not loving the pipes and wood scattered around our small apartment, so time is of the essence!

-I was hoping something like a pipe threader existed, but instead of threading the pipes it would take off .1mm

-I have 29 pipes and 2 sides to each pipe

-I tried hand sanding the steel pipe even after the HCl bath and didn't make much progress.
-heating the fittings isn't really an option as I need to be able to take it apart easily.

-I've considered dumping the aluminum in the HCl solution for an hour to possibly reduce there inner diameter, but I'm not sure that's a great idea

Comment: A muffler shop should have a machine that reduces the ends without removing metal.  It squeezes the end down so it slips into the next pipe.

Comment: If a muffler shop cannot do that size and the pipe is thick enough, a bench grinder should remove that amount easy.  You want to keep 80 to 90% of the original thickness.  It will make a dusty mess plus quite a few sparks, so fire risk.

Comment: Or hog out the fittings a bit too...

Comment: If the inside diameter of the fitting is bigger than the outside diameter of the pipe, then don't you have the opposite problem? Or you stated the issue backwards...

Comment: @crip659 I'm not sure a muffler shop could handle the thick wall of galvanized steel tubing that we seem to be dealing with. Muffler pipe tends to be pretty thin walled. Worth a shot, though...

Comment: wrap course sandpaper around the end of pipe and twist a bunch until it erodes enough steel away that it fits, you might need a few strips of sandpaper, but it's cheap and effective. The harder you squeeze the paper the faster it will shave the pipe. If that doesn't work, look into electrolysis.

Answer (score 3):

Chuck them up in your metal lathe and cut the excess off.

Or hire your local machine shop to do that, if you don't have a metal lathe and can't fit one into your house/apartment/budget.

A metal lathe can also cut threads, so this is pretty much exactly the tool you were looking for.

*Or, order different fittings, or drill out the fittings.*

Comment: Given the fitting has a larger diameter than the pipe then *adding* material with a lathe is possible - metal spraying, welding etc

Comment: I think that's a mis-statement, given the described attempts to remove metal from the pipe. And a simple shim would work if it were the case.